# Keeping track of Online and Offline status in MVC C# webpage with NodeJS

Tags: c#, node.js, model-view-controller

I have a MVC C# Webpage. I use NodeJs express module for a real time chat feature.

The real time chat works well, I am however a novice in NodeJs.

In my chat page, users can add a favorite lists of users they like to chat with. What I want to do is put a green or red dot next to each user in their favorites list so they can see who is online.

Keeping track of every users online status is fairly straight forward, even without Node JS. I could just make a a simple ajax call on every action in the page which updates the users last activity. If the activity is less than 10 minutes old, my site will consider them online.

However the problem  comes when I want that status to be shown in real time to the user in the chat page. Each user may have 20-30 users in their list. So ajax polling every minute or so, sounds a like it may get a bit messy? (200 users polling the server every minute asking about 30 other users status)

What logic is best used in a situation like this?

Comment: have you considered using sockets for real-time chat app? something like socket.io or any other web sockets implementation? otherwise you have to live with the fact that online status would lag behind unless you are prepared to flood your servers with polling as you correctly expect it to happen

Comment: I already use socket.io for my real time chat..

Comment: i will do more research into node.js (socket.io) and online status's